# Random characters instead of String input in Combobox Items?

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I am trying to create a choicebox in my application using javafx/scenebuilder in IntelliJ but so far am not able to get Strings to show as menu items - in the example screenshot below I have just tried to create an option with the letter C? The code I have used is below. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? I thought it might be a font issue but I can't find a way to change the font of the menu items.

[image: example]

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="127.5">
               <children>
                  <Text fill="WHITE" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="I" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="11.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="4.0">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="Courier Bold" size="40.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Text>
                  <ChoiceBox fx:id="keyChoice" prefWidth="79.0" style="-fx-background-color: #FBC5B8;" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="8.0">
                      <items>
                          <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                              <String fx:value="C" />
                          </FXCollections>
                      </items>
                  </ChoiceBox>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Not saying this is the cause of your problem, but why are you trying to place a `MenuItem` in a `ChoiceBox`?  It's almost always wrong to use UI objects as the items of a `ChoiceBox` (or `ComboBox`, `TableView`, `ListView`, etc.).

Comment: @Slaw Ah I forgot to change this back to as I had it before, I will update the question (both ways give a similar error though with different random characters). This was one of my many attempts to solve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this was a font issue as suspected, couldn't find a way to change it in FXML so created a CSS file which works fine.

```
.choice-box .menu-item .label {
-fx-font-family: "monospace";
}

.choice-box {
-fx-font-family: "monospace";
}
```